# How to declare Iterator and DenseMatrix type variable in operation mapPartition of RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a double array in mapPartition of RDD,and when I declare an iterator or DenseMatrix by this double array.I found that the iterator and matrix are empty.My test codes are as below:

```
val RandXts = data.map{
line =>
  val fields = patterns.findAllIn(line).toArray.map(_.toDouble)
  fields(fields.length-1)
}.repartition(2)

val res = RandXts.mapPartitions(x=>{
val matrix = new DenseMatrix(x.length,1,x.toArray)
val arr = matrix.toArray
println(k.length)
(matrix::List[DenseMatrix[Double]]()).iterator
})
```

As shown above,the line declare matrix will cause an error.The error message are as below:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Storage array has size 0 but indices can grow as large as 124
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "As shown above, the variables its and matrix are all empty" - how is it shown above? It's not... and what's the input?

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception (your updated code doesn't compile: `k` is not defined; `(matrix::List[DenseMatrix[Double]]())` is not valid Scala code). When I fix these I get a different error (in matrix construction) which is solved by what I've already answered - `x` is an _iterator_ and you're accessing it twice, when you call `x.toArray` after calling `x.length` you'll get an **empty Array**. Call `toArray` _first_ and use the resulting array to get the length. Bottom line - I think the exception comes from the code building `RandXts` with which I can't help - there's no sample data.

Comment: Yeah,you are right that I called `x.toArray` after calling `x.length`.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great! I updated the answer again according to these updates. Please accept/upvote it for future readers' reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls `x.length` and then passes `x` again to the `DenseMatrix` constructor. Since `x` is an iterator, calling `length` "consumes" the iterator, hence passing it again will result in an *empty* collection.

To fix this - scan the iterator once (by converting it into an array):

```
val res: RDD[DenseMatrix] = RandXts.mapPartitions(x => {
  val arr = x.toArray // scan iterator only once
  val matrix = new DenseMatrix(arr.length, 1, arr)
  Seq(matrix).iterator // this is the return value
})
```

For example, for input `val RandXts = sc.parallelize(Seq(0.5, 0.6, 0.8))`, printing the result shows that it contains a single Matrix with these values:

```
res.collect().foreach(println)
// prints: 
// 0.5  
// 0.6  
// 0.8
```

Comment: I know that mapPartitions expects such function.But the return value is not the problem(of course,my test codes did not give the right return value),my issue is that I found that those variables of type iterator and DenseMatrix(maybe should have some other types) declared from 'x' is empty.As my test codes shown,if I print the length of 'its',its length is zero.

Comment: First - see updated answer. Second - please provide all the information in the question - the code that actually fails is missing so it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have updated the question.Please have a look.